# How the Ceil function is calculating the value if this expression?

Tags: python

```
ceil((14.84 - 14.04)/0.08)

output - 11
```

I was expecting the output to be 10 when manually calculated but when running it in python, it is giving output as 11

Comment: Print the value without calling `ceil()`. It's `10.000000000000009`

Comment: Also try printing `14.84 - 14.04`. It's not exactly `.80`.

Answer (score 1):

[Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken#:%7E:text=It%27s%20broken%20in%20the%20exact,It%27s%20impossible%20to%20do%20exactly!)

The float value from your equation is actually `10.000000000000009` because of how floats are handled (see link for more information). So, even though it is such a small amount above `10` the ceiling function will still place it at `11`.

You can try rounding the number to a decimal point that you trust to get the value you want:

```py
from math import ceil

ceil(round((14.84 - 14.04)/0.08, 2))
```

Output: `10`